# How to auto-generate a mail with the password created after clicking on "Create User" button in Alfresco New User page?

Tags: java, alfresco, email, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

How can we auto-generate a mail with the new user's password as soon as we click on the create user button in Alfresco New User page.
Do we need to create any webscript or action which can redirect to create user action and a corresponding mail will be generated automatically.
Please let me know how to create the link between Create User button and the mail to the new user.

Comment: There's probably half a dozen different ways to do this... How are you currently customising Alfresco? AMPs with Java code in? AMPs with JavaScript? Rules? Other?

Comment: AMPs with java code

Comment: I don't think it is an Alfresco issue

Comment: Yagami this was an Alfresco UI query which is solved by the help of Imagine's javascript code. Please do not demotivate a learner if he is asking doubts.

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately any thing in alfresco is node. User is also one type of node in alfresco.As per my perspective the best solution is to create a behavior and send an email.

Below is detail for implementation of behaviour in alfresco.

https://www.alfresco.com/blogs/lcabaceira/2015/04/07/alfresco-behaviours-and-policies/

This is one link for behaviour in alfresco.You will find multiple link for behaviour in alfresco.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate on this??

Answer (score 1):

Create the new rule:

- on `Repository > User Homes` folder
- when: `Items are created or enter this folder`
- perform action: `Execute script`:

  ```
  if (document.isContainer && document.displayPath == "/Company Home/User Homes") {
      var owner = document.properties["cm:owner"];
      var pNode = people.getPerson(owner);
      if (pNode!=null && pNode.exists()){

          var userName = pNode.properties.userName;
          var email = pNode.properties.email;
          var randPassword = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 30)+"-"+(Date.now());

          people.setPassword(userName, randPassword);
          logger.debug("Invitation mail: User "+userName+" password has been changed.");

          var mail = actions.create("mail");
          //mail.parameters.from = "noreply@customdomain";
          mail.parameters.to = email; 
          mail.parameters.subject = "Welcome to the jungle, login: "+userName+", password: "+randPassword;
          mail.parameters.template = companyhome.childByNamePath("Data Dictionary/Email Templates/Invite Email Templates/invite_user_email.ftl");
          var templateModel = new Array();
          templateModel['newPassword'] = randPassword; // use ${newPassword} expression inside template
          mail.parameters.template_model = templateModel;
          mail.executeAsynchronously(document);
          logger.debug("Invitation mail has been sent to "+email);
      } else {
          logger.warn("Invitation mail: User not found: "+owner);
      }
  } else {
      logger.warn("Invitation mail: Document "+document.name+" / "+document.nodeRef+" is not a user home folder.");
  }
  ```

You can use https://papercut.codeplex.com/ to test it, Alfresco configuration:

```
# smtp settings
mail.host=localhost
mail.port=25
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.auth=false
# mail.smtp.timeout=30000
# mail.smtp.debug=true
```

Comment: So this will be in javascript... will try this out and let you know...

Comment: This code has helped a lot...