# Auto-generation of email with username and random password on creation of new user

Tags: java, alfresco

I have created a class NewUserEmail to auto generate an email with username and password while creating a new user. I am able to create the password but whenever I am trying to log in with that password, its not logging in. I am not able to generate my mail. Please guide me and let me know what is wrong with my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException;
import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ClasspathScriptLocation;
import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.PolicyComponent;
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil;
import org.alfresco.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.ChildAssociationRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.PersonService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessagePreparator;

public class NewUserEmail implements NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NewUserEmail.class);
    private PolicyComponent policyComponent;
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private PersonService personService;
    private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;
    protected String userName = null;
    protected String password = null;
    protected String email = null;
    protected String subject = null;
    protected String body = null;

    private static final String NEW_USER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = "alfresco/module/demoact1-repo/template/new_user_email.ftl";
    private static final String EMAIL_FROM = "no-reply@eisenvault.com";

    public void init() {
        this.email = "";
        this.userName = "";
        this.password = "";
        this.subject = "New User Alfresco";
        this.body = "";
        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                QName.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onCreateNode"),
                ContentModel.TYPE_PERSON,
                new JavaBehaviour(this, "ReportUser", org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour.NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT)
        );
    }

    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) logger.info(" NewUserEmail Node create policy fired");
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    public void setPolicyComponent(PolicyComponent policyComponent) {
        this.policyComponent = policyComponent;
    }

    public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return this.subject;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return this.body;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return this.userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


    public void ReportUser(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        NodeRef personRef = childAssocRef.getChildRef();
        this.userName = (String) this.nodeService.getProperty(personRef, ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME);
        this.email = (String) this.nodeService.getProperty(personRef, ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL);
        sendEmail();
    }


    public void sendEmail() throws AlfrescoRuntimeException {
        Map<String, Object> templateModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (getEmail() != null && getEmail() != "") {
            Set<NodeRef> result = serviceRegistry.getPersonService().getPeopleFilteredByProperty(ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL, getEmail(), 1);
            if (result.size() == 1) {
                changePassword(getUserName());
                ClasspathScriptLocation location = new ClasspathScriptLocation(NEW_USER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
                try {
                    if (location.getInputStream() != null) {
                        // Check that there is a template
                        templateModel.put("userName", getUserName());
                        templateModel.put("password", getPassword());
                        this.body = serviceRegistry.getTemplateService().processTemplate("freemarker", NEW_USER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, templateModel);
                    }
                } catch (AlfrescoRuntimeException e) {
                    // If template isn't found, email is constructed "manually"
                    logger.error("Email Template not found " + NEW_USER_EMAIL_TEMPLATE);
                    this.body = "<html> <body> <p> A new User has been created.</p>" +
                            "<p>Hello, </p><p>Your username is " + getUserName() + " and your " +
                            "password is " + getPassword() + "</p> " +
                            "<p>We strongly advise you to change your password when you log in for the first time.</p>" +
                            "Regards</body> </html>";
                    //send();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void send() {
        MimeMessagePreparator mailPreparer = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo(getEmail());
                message.setSubject(getSubject());
                message.setText(getBody(), true);
                message.setFrom(EMAIL_FROM);
            }
        };
    }

    public void changePassword(String password) {
        AuthenticationUtil.setRunAsUserSystem();
        Set<NodeRef> result = serviceRegistry.getPersonService().getPeopleFilteredByProperty(ContentModel.PROP_EMAIL, getEmail(), 1);
        if (result.size() == 1) {
            Object[] userNodeRefs = result.toArray();
            NodeRef userNodeRef = (NodeRef) userNodeRefs[0];
            String username = (String) serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getProperty(userNodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME);
            // Generate random password
            String newPassword = Password.generatePassword();
            char[] cadChars = new char[newPassword.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < newPassword.length(); i++) {
                cadChars[i] = newPassword.charAt(i);
            }
            serviceRegistry.getAuthenticationService().setAuthentication(username, newPassword.toCharArray());
            setPassword(newPassword);
            System.out.println("Password is :" + newPassword);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522119/conversion-of-my-alfresco-javascript-file-into-java-class/40525106#40525106 is it different ?

Comment: Not able to retrieve my answer based on this...

Comment: I am not allowed to use : properties.put(ContentModel.PROP_PASSWORD,randPassword);

Comment: You should remove or accept answers for this related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080238/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40150331/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260401/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522119/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40526757/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working solution.

resource/alfresco/extension/new-user-email-context.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">    
    <bean id="newUserEmail" class="demo.NewUserEmail">
        <property name="policyComponent" ref="policyComponent"/>
        <property name="nodeService" ref="nodeService"/>
        <property name="personService" ref="personService"/>
        <property name="passwordGenerator" ref="passwordGenerator"/>
        <property name="authenticationService" ref="authenticationService"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

demo.NewUserEmail.java:

```
package demo;
import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.repo.node.NodeServicePolicies;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.*;
import org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.PasswordGenerator;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.*;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.security.*;
import org.alfresco.util.PropertyCheck;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;

public class NewUserEmail implements 
    NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy, InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void onCreateNode(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        notifyUser(childAssocRef);
    }

    private void notifyUser(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef) {
        NodeRef personRef = childAssocRef.getChildRef();
        // get the user name
        String username = (String) this.nodeService.getProperty(
            personRef, ContentModel.PROP_USERNAME);
        // generate the new password (Alfresco's rules)
        String newPassword = passwordGenerator.generatePassword();
        // set the new password
        authenticationService.setAuthentication(username, newPassword.toCharArray());
        // send default notification to the user
        personService.notifyPerson(username, newPassword);
    }

    private PolicyComponent policyComponent;
    private NodeService nodeService;
    private PersonService personService;
    private PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator;
    private MutableAuthenticationService authenticationService;

    public void setPolicyComponent(PolicyComponent policyComponent) {
        this.policyComponent = policyComponent;
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }

    public void setPersonService(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    public void setPasswordGenerator(PasswordGenerator passwordGenerator) {
        this.passwordGenerator = passwordGenerator;
    }

    public void setAuthenticationService(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        if (authenticationService instanceof MutableAuthenticationService) {
            this.authenticationService = (MutableAuthenticationService) authenticationService;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "policyComponent", policyComponent);
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "nodeService", nodeService);
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "passwordGenerator", passwordGenerator);
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "authenticationService", authenticationService);
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "personService", personService);

        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME,
                ContentModel.TYPE_PERSON,
                new JavaBehaviour(this,
                        NodeServicePolicies.OnCreateNodePolicy.QNAME.getLocalName(),
                        Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.TRANSACTION_COMMIT
                )
        );
    }


}
```

Comment: Will give you all the changes I had made for this.

Comment: public class Password {
 
 private static final int  length = 8;
    
    private static final String NUMBERS = "0123456789";
   
    private static final String UPPERCASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  
    private static final String LOWERCASE = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    
    public static String generatePassword() {
       String key = NUMBERS + UPPERCASE + LOWERCASE;
       String pswd = "";
  
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
          pswd+=(key.charAt((int)(Math.random() * key.length())));
       }
  
       return pswd;
    }
    

}

Comment: <bean id="NewUserEmail" class="com.eisenvault.autoMailgenerate.NewUserEmail" init-method="init" >
       <property name="nodeService">   
         <ref bean="nodeService" />
      </property>
      <property name="policyComponent">
         <ref bean="policyComponent" />
      </property>
      <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry"/>
    </bean>

Comment: <html>
<body>
<p>A new User has been created.</p>
<p>Hello, </p>
<p>Your username is ${userName} and your password is ${password} </p>


<p>We strongly advise you to change your password when you log in for the first time.</p>


Regards
</body>
</html>

Comment: Above is the new_user_email.ftl file where I have created the mail body

Comment: Getting exception with the bean:

Comment: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'NewUserEmail' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/demoact1-repo/context/service-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.repo.policy.PolicyException: Method reportUser not found or accessible on class com.eisenvault.autoMailgenerate.NewUserEmail

Comment: finally got what I wanted to.......I am really thankful.....Got the password with the mail.... :)

Comment: You need to mark an answer as correct (the green check image) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers

Comment: Done...Please check

Comment: It is ok :), you can click an Arrow up too (maybe you have not enough reputation to do this)

Comment: And, you know it, learn Java, Spring IoC, Angular 2... and after this you will be ready to learn programming Alfresco https://www.codeschool.com/free-weekend

Comment: That will be great :)